# Blank terminal in PyCharm?

Tags: terminal, pycharm

So here's the problem, every time I open a project in Pycharm and attempt to use the embedded terminal (with Alt + F12) - the only thing that appears is a blank tab with a blinking cursor icon. [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B3SE.png)

To fix the problem, I have tried the following to no avail:

1. Resetting Pycharm
2. Deleting the .idea folder of an existing project and recreating under "New Project".
3. Resetting and switching the shell path under "Settings --> Terminal
   --> Tools --> Shell Path" to Powershell and a more specific version of Command Prompt.

Looking at existing bugs for PyCharm on JetBrains' site doesn't appear to reveal any currently tracked bugs that match this problem.

If anyone has any ideas on how to remedy this situation, that would be of tremendous help.

Comment: Which PyCharm version do you use? Looks similar to a known bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200147